# Should I send a second (but not consecutive) follow-up email?

Tags: graduate-school, advisor, masters, email

By the end of the term, I am supposed to choose my MA supervisor. Normally, I agreed to meet her to confer on a possible common area of interest this week. On Monday, I sent her an email asking when we could meet and she hasn't still replied. It's now Sunday in Turkey, so it has been six days.

I want to send a follow up email but the problem is that I sent another follow up email on the same issue two or three weeks ago when I first contacted to ask whether I can study with her. If I send a second email this time as well, I fear that I could seem rude and annoying. What should I do here? Since the deadline is one month from now on, I want to settle this issue.

Comment: Depending on where your prospective supervisor lives and works, they may not be back at work yet after Christmas and New Year's. I would wait until the end of next week before sending another follow up. Also, have you already been accepted for the MA? Or do you need this supervisor to accept you first?

Comment: @astronat Yes, I have already been accepted. In Turkey, you have to choose your MA thesis advisor/supervisor by the end of the first semester once you are admitted.

Comment: E-mails can get lost in the cyberspace and with COVID pandemic everywhere there may be many more serious reasons for not getting replies. I would wait a bit (like one more week if the deadline is within a month) and then, if still there is no response, resend the e-mail with a short apology for doing it again. If there is still no response after that and the deadline gets close, I might even go as far as to contact the department head and politely inquire if everything is OK unless you have some less direct means to check it. I hope she'll reply long before that though :-)